# selecting pairs of records php array

Tags: php

I need to create a code that will take the value of $time[1] and subtract the value of $time[2], then takes the value of $time[3] and subtracts the value of $time[4], and so on, until it runs out of $time records. It should keep a running total.

Mock data:

```
$time[1] = "2017-08-28 18:30:00";
$time[2] = "2017-08-28 14:00:00";
$time[3] = "2017-08-28 13:00:00";
$time[4] = "2017-08-28 12:45:00";
$time[5] = "2017-08-28 12:30:00";
$time[6] = "2017-08-28 12:00:00";
```

For example: [1]-[2]=4.5 hours, [3]-[4]=0.25 hours, [5]-[6]=0.5 hours; total=5.25 hours.

```
$hourdiff = round((strtotime($time[1]) - strtotime($time[2]))/3600, 1); //gives you the quantity of hours worked between 2 records
```

I need a way to select records 1 and 2, calculate the $hourdiff, add it to the running total, then select records 3 and 4, calculate the $hourdiff, add it to the running total, etc. until there are no records left to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($time) - 1; $i++) {
    $hourdiff = round((strtotime($time[$i + 1]) - strtotime($time[$i]))/3600, 1);
    echo "The difference is: $hourdiff" . "<br />";
}
```

This will echo out the five differences in time.

Note that you need to start with the `$i` at 1, because you can't subtract 'nothing' from the first event! To counter this, you need to stop the index one short of the count.

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/Vdi24)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Aha thank you so much for that "for" loop, it was the missing piece and I didn't fully understand how it was supposed to work (whether it should be a while loop or a for or foreach loop or whatever). I just added "$x=$x+1" to the bottom of your loop and now it only calculates the difference between the records in pairs like I need. So very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array, but instead of adding 1 to the iterating variable, add two (and check for an out of bounds error):

```
<?php
$time[0] = "2017-08-28 18:30:00";
$time[1] = "2017-08-28 14:00:00";
$time[2] = "2017-08-28 13:00:00";
$time[3] = "2017-08-28 12:45:00";
$time[4] = "2017-08-28 12:30:00";
$time[5] = "2017-08-28 12:00:00";
$total = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($time); $i += 2) {
    if ($i + 1 > count($time) - 1) break; // check of out of bounds
    $total += round((strtotime($time[$i]) - strtotime($time[$i + 1]))/3600, 1); // add diff of next two numbers
}
echo $total;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ROKpY)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$time[1] = "2017-08-28 18:30:00";
$time[2] = "2017-08-28 14:00:00";
$time[3] = "2017-08-28 13:00:00";
$time[4] = "2017-08-28 12:45:00";
$time[5] = "2017-08-28 12:30:00";
$time[6] = "2017-08-28 12:00:00";

$times = array();

$total = 0;

foreach ($time as $n => $t0) {
    if ($n % 2) {
        continue;
    }
    $t1 = strtotime($time[$n - 1]);
    $t2 = strtotime($t0);
    $k = sprintf('%s-%s', $n - 1, $n);
    $diff = ($t1 - $t2) / 3600;
    $times[$k] = sprintf('%.2f hours', $diff);
    $total += $diff;
}


print_r($times);
printf('TOTAL : %s hours', $total);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1-2] => 4.50 hours
    [3-4] => 0.25 hours
    [5-6] => 0.50 hours
)
TOTAL : 5.25 hours
```

Or yo can try with [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

```
$time[1] = "2017-08-28 18:30:00";
$time[2] = "2017-08-28 14:00:00";
$time[3] = "2017-08-28 13:00:00";
$time[4] = "2017-08-28 12:45:00";
$time[5] = "2017-08-28 12:30:00";
$time[6] = "2017-08-28 12:00:00";

$times = array();

$total = new DateTime;

foreach ($time as $n => $t0) {
    if ($n % 2) {
        continue;
    }
    $t1 = new DateTime($time[$n - 1]);
    $t2 = new DateTime($t0);
    $k = sprintf('%s-%s', $n - 1, $n);
    $diff = $t1->diff($t2);
    $times[$k] = $diff->format('%h hour(s) %i min(s) %s sec(s)');
    $total = $total->add($diff);
}

$total = ($total->diff(new DateTime))->format('%h hour(s) %i min(s) %s sec(s)');

print_r($times);
printf('TOTAL : %s', $total);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1-2] => 4 hour(s) 30 min(s) 0 sec(s)
    [3-4] => 0 hour(s) 15 min(s) 0 sec(s)
    [5-6] => 0 hour(s) 30 min(s) 0 sec(s)
)
TOTAL : 5 hour(s) 15 min(s) 0 sec(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to group into pairs, then [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to sum the differences:

```
$total = array_reduce(
    array_chunk($time, 2),
    function ($total, $pair) {
        return $total + (strtotime($pair[0]) - strtotime($pair[1]));
    },
    0
);
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/fsgdC)

The input `$time` is an array of time-like strings, suitable for passing to [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). The resulting `$total` will be an integer number of seconds.